# Flutter Firebase Messaging only works on iOS Simulator

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm use the [Flutter Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging#-readme-tab-) package for Firebase messaging for iOS and Android. I have no issues with Android receiving messages. For iOS I only get any calls from `onMessage` if I am running the Simulator and not a real device. I have followed the step by step instructions. Any ideas?